# Apply step function to values

Tags: kdb

I have the following table:

```
t:([]sym:`eae`oco`khd`dga`eob`iog`edg`kio`gme`iko; val:1 0 5 1 0 0 1 7 6 3)

sym val
-------
eae 1  
oco 0  
khd 5  
dga 1  
eob 0  
iog 0  
edg 1  
kio 7  
gme 6  
iko 3
```

What I want is to assign some `bucket` value according to the following rules:

```
if 0 <= val < 1, then bucket = 3 
if 1 <= val < 3, then bucket = 8
if 3 <= val < 5, then bucket = 20
if 5 <= val    , then bucket = 30
```

So similar to applying a step function to the values `val`.
The resulting table should look like this:

```
sym val bucket
--------------
eae 1   8     
oco 0   3     
khd 5   30    
dga 1   8     
eob 0   3     
iog 0   3     
edg 1   8     
kio 7   30    
gme 6   30    
iko 3   20
```

Of course, I don't want to apply `if[if[...]]`, and I am looking for an elegant q-ist solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works:

```
update bucket: (`s#0 1 3 5!3 8 20 30)[val] from t
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I prefer the step-function-dictionary approach by @Anonymouse, for completeness another approach is to use an asof join

```
q)aj[`val;t;([]val:0 1 3 5;bucket:3 8 20 30)]
sym val bucket
--------------
eae 1   8
oco 0   3
khd 5   30
dga 1   8
eob 0   3
iog 0   3
edg 1   8
kio 7   30
gme 6   30
iko 3   20
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called 'stepped dictionary'. Though @Anonymouse has already covered the dictionary way of using it, however, there is also a slightly different way of using it by converting it to a stepped `keyed-table`; this will make it easier to join with any other table using `lj`:

```
q)t:([]sym:`eae`oco`khd`dga`eob`iog`edg`kio`gme`iko; val:1 0 5 1 0 0 1 7 6 3)
q)sd:`s#([val:0 1 3 5] bucket:3 8 20 30)
q)t lj sd
```